# What will be the execution flow for the following procedure?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Below is the code for my stored procedure but I am not completely clear with the flow of execution. How the @@RAISERROR() in my case will work and how it will change the normal flow? Also what does the number 10 & 1 mean in that function. There are few other numbers also that can be used instead of 10 & 1 so how all the number affects flow of execution. Please let me know if my coding structure of style is bad/wrong or if there is any scope for improvement.
Below is my code.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spAddressMaster 
@Mode           varchar(20),
@Street         varchar(MAX),
@City           varchar(300),
@State          varchar(300),
@Country        varchar(300),
@PostalCode     int,
@Remarks        varchar(MAX),
@Type           varchar(300)
AS
BEGIN
BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY
--INSERT MODE--
IF(@Mode='INSERT')
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [AddressMST] (
                [Street],
                [City],
                [State],
                [Country],
                [PostalCode],
                [Remarks],
                [Type]
                )
    VALUES (
        @Street,
        @City,
        @State,
        @Country,
        @PostalCode,
        @Remarks,
        @Type
    ) 
IF(@@ERROR<>0)
    RAISERROR('Insert Operation Fail',10,1)
END
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF(@@ERROR<>0)
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE()
    END 
END CATCH
END
GO
```

Comment: you could easily test yourself with a few PRINT statements...

Comment: @Mitch Wheat I need better explanation for @@RAISEERROR() function in my case which I think I can get with PRINT...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you have a big problem: you have a `BEGIN TRANSACTION` without any `COMMIT`. That’s about as wrong as you can get when programming for databases! Use this general structure:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

BEGIN TRY

…do stuff…

COMMIT
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

…error handling…

ROLLBACK

END CATCH
```

Next up, when you are executing code within a `BEGIN TRY` block, if any errors are raised execution is *immediately* transferrred to the `BEGIN CATCH` block. This means that the `IF(@@ERROR<>0)` block will only ever be executed when no errors have occured, i.e. @@ERROR will always be 0.

As for the meaning of the 10 and 1 in the RAISERROR, that is complex, detailed, and best explained in SQL Server books online under the entry “RAISERROR”. Here’s the [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

**MSDN Doc**

```
Generates an error message and initiates error processing for the session.
RAISERROR can either reference a user-defined message stored in the sys.messages catalog
view or build a message dynamically. The message is returned as a server error message
to the calling application or to an associated CATCH block of a TRY…CATCH construct.
```

For more refer [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)